# How to fprintf on file with recursive

Tags: c, recursion

I'm a newbie with recursion.  How do I `fopen` and `fclose` a file in a recursive function?

```
void make(LINK lis, char *name, int flag, FILE *f)
{
    if (lis == NULL) {
        fclose(f);
    }
    else {
        if (flag == 0) {
            FILE *f = fopen(name, "w");
            flag = 1;
        }
        else {
            fprintf(f, "CODICE: %d\n", lis->d.codice);
            make(lis->next, name, 1, f);
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to recursively write "codice" --> CODE in a file.

Comment: Your [mcve] don't compile and I don't understand your question.

Comment: This isn't recursive.  Are `make` and `crea` supposed to be the same function?

Comment: Why are you doing this recursively?  This case is better handled iteratively, for obvious reasons: you don't find it obvious how to open and close the file.

Comment: Sorry, crea --> make..

Answer (score 1):

Your most immediate problem is that on the first call, you open the file and then return to the main program, without processing anything.  Opening the file should be a simple test, not an if-then-*else*.

```
void make(LINK lis, char *name, FILE *f)
{
    if (!lis) {
        fclose(f);
    }
    else {
        if (f) {
            f = fopen(name, "w");
            }
        fprintf(f, "CODICE: %d\n", lis->d.codice);
        make(lis->next, name, f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fopen and fclose a file in a recursive function?

Be sure to do so at the same level of recursion.

---

Consider first how the nth and first would look separately:

```
void make_nth(LINK lis, FILE *outf) {
  if (lis) {
    fprintf(outf, "CODICE: %d\n", lis->d.codice);
    make_nth(lis->next, outf);
  }
}

void make_1st(LINK lis, const char *name) {
  FILE *f = fopen(name, "w");
  if (f) {
    make_nth(lis, f);
    fclose(f);
  }
}

// Usage
LINK lis = ...;
make_1st(lis, codice.txt);
```

Now put that together.  Various ways exist to do this.

```
void make(LINK lis, const char *name, FILE *outf) {
  if (name) {
    assert(outf == NULL);
    FILE *f = fopen(name, "w");
    if (f) {
      make(lis, NULL, f);
      fclose(f);
    }
  } else {
    if (lis) {
      fprintf(outf, "CODICE: %d\n", lis->d.codice);
      make(lis->next, NULL, outf);
    }
  }
}

// Usage
LINK lis = ...;
make(lis, codice.txt, NULL);
```